# Dynamic files name load and processing with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, printf

I'm processing some .xlsx, there are named like time1_drug1,time1_drug2,until tiume6_drug5 (30 files in total). I want to load these xlsx to R and name them to dataset such as t1d1, t2d2.
I tried to use sprintf, but I cannot figure out how to make valid.

```
for(i in 1:6) {
  for(j in 1:5) {
sprintf("time%i","drug%j,i,j)=read.xlsx("/Users/pathway/dataset/time_sprintf(%i,i)_drug(%j,j).xlsx", 1)}
names(sprintf("t%i","d%j,i,j))=c("result", "testF","TestN")
sprintf("t%i","d%j,i,j)$Discription[which(sprintf("t%i","d%j,i,j)$testF>=1&sprintf("t%i","d%j,i,j)$TestN>=2)]="High+High"
}
}
```

I expect to get 30 data like t1d1 till t6d5.

Comment: Did my code work?

Comment: Sure! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should (almost) never use `assign`. When reading multiple files into R you should (almost) always put them in a named list.

A rough outline of a much better approach is this:

```
# Put all the excel files in a directory and this retrieves all their paths
f <- dir("/Users/pathway/dataset/",full.names = TRUE)
# Read all files into a list
drug_time <- lapply(X = f,FUN = read.xlsx)
# Name each list element based on the file name
names(drug_time) <- gsub(pattern = ".xlsx",replacement = "",x = basename(f),fixed = TRUE)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `for` loop as you are, but you should also use the `assign` function:

```
for(i in 1:6){
for(j in 1:5){
assign(paste0('t', i, '_', 'd', j), read.xlsx(paste0("/Users/pathway/dataset/time_",i,"_drug",j,".xlsx"), 1))
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I got one more question.

Comment: @HHuang what’s your question?

Comment: I want to rename column for every timei_drug_j as A B C what code should I use?

Comment: assign(names(paste0('time', i, '_', 'drug', j)),c("pERK", "NGFR","AXL")) this seem to be an error

Comment: and I want to use which function to create a fourth column, time1_drug1$Discription[which(time1_drug1$NGFR>=2&time1_drug1$AXL>=1.5)]="NFGR High&AXL High"